# Generating more than 1 directory with a single os.mkdir function (Python)

Tags: python, linux, windows, directory, create-directory

I made a function in Python (WinOS) that ends up creating new directories (where future work is stored). So at some point, I define the directories and after I use `os.mkdir(os.pahth.join('current_dir', 'new_dir1', 'new_dir2'))`. And it works.

The problem is that this same function is not working on Linux OS (Ubuntu). In Linux I can only generate a single directory. I.e.:

`os.mkdir(os.path.join('current_dir', 'new_dir1', 'new_dir2'))` returns error :

> (OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/[current_dir]/new_dir1/new_dir2')

but:

`os.mkdir(os.path.join('current_dir', 'new_dir1'))` - This works, returns the single directory

but I need to create 2 directories in Linux, not one...

I have tried several "easy combos" such as

```
new_dirs = os.path.join('new_dir1', 'new_dir2')
os.mkdir(os.path.join('current_dir', new_dirs)
```

returns the same error:

> OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/[current_dir]/new_dir1/new_dir2'

What I do (and works in Linux) is the next:

```py
#Generate the path for the output files
working_path = os.path.join(outfile_path, 'First_Corregistration', 'Split_Area', '') 
#Verify is the path exist, if not, create it.
if not os.path.exists(working_path):
    os.mkdir(working_path)
```

Can somebody tell me how to create 2 or more new directories (one inside the other) with Linux. I highlight again what is more weird: My current solution works with Windows,  but not with Linux.

Comment: seems like a job for... os.makedirs (not os.makedir), try, see if it works. 
reference - https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkdirs

Comment: Yes! It works, it makes the job! It is interesting because Windows works without this function.

Comment: yes this is actually interesting, i'll try to find why and if i will find i will add it to my answer. don't forget to mark the correct answer if it is solved :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of `os.mkdir` use `os.makedirs`, should work.
simple example:

```
os.makedirs("brand/new/directory")
```

should create the directories: `brand`, `new` and `directory`

from https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkdirs :

> Recursive directory creation function. Like mkdir(), but makes all intermediate-level directories needed to contain the leaf directory.